# Geolocalization of my website

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache2, geotargeting

I have a big problem with GeoIP. My website has the following structure

- www.domain.com
- it.domain.com
- de.domain.com

I use the MaxMind GeoIP module in Apache to redirect users to the appropriate site base on their country.

My problem is when a user from Italy visits it.domain.com: if ge wants to change language and try to open www.domain.com, he is redirected back to it.domain.com. How can I prevent redirection when a user selects a language.

Answer (score 1):

Forget geolocation - it's fundamentally flawed as you have noted. Browsers send an Accept-Language header, check that on your www. site and flip the user, once, to the language they say they prefer. On the subdomains, provide change-language links but do not do any checks.

I develop multi-lingual sites from Japan (read: do this a lot), my standard .htaccess rule for Japanese speakers looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule .* http://ja.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://ja.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And of course there's no database to deal with. Japanese speakers on vacation in Brazil will still see the page in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cookie for this on `*.domain.com`. Special cookie value (let's say `lang`) should only be set if user clicks on any of the flags. Now on `www.domain.com` when routing users to localized websites you first check if cookie with `lang` value is set, if so, you redirect to a page with `lang` specified in the cookie. If, however, such cookie would not exist, then your redirection should work as usual.